# Which technology is used in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I am wondering which technology is used by Google in Google Analytics.
When i checked my website's in Google Analytics real time overview, i find out that there is no http request in network monitor.

Can any one tell me which technology is this..

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: I'm pretty certain Google keeps its technology details secret.

Answer (score 0):

Every part of the Google Analytics collection is based upon HTTP requests with the [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/).

```
POST /collect HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google-analytics.com

payload_data
```

You are likely using [Analytics.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/) which collects information from the user agent and sends hits to www.google-analytics.com

Comment: How can i explain that what i want to know. :(